# Very low accuracy on Digit recgonition dataset with images having 4 channels, using Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am currently working on a digit recognition challenge by **Analytics Vidhya**, the link to which is https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-identify-the-digits/ . 
The images in the dataset pertaining to this challenge are of dimensions **28*28*4** (28 = length = width , 4 = no. of channels).The code I have implemented is:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Flatten,Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
import numpy as np
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
# define the larger model
def larger_model():
# create model
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(4, 28, 28),activation='relu',padding='same'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.25))
  model.add(Conv2D(15, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
  # Compile model
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model
def loadImages(path):
# return array of images

  imagesList = listdir(path)
  loadedImages = []
  for image in imagesList:
    img = io.imread(path + "/" + image,as_grey = False)
    loadedImages.append(np.array(img)) 
  return loadedImages
path = "C:/Users/Farz Jamal/Downloads/mnist/Train/Images/train" #path_to_train_dataset 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Farz Jamal/Downloads/mnist/Train/train.csv") #path_to_class_labels
y = np.array(df['label'])
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split as ttt
x_train,x_val,y_train,y_val = ttt(imgs,y,test_size = 0.2)
```

Continued Code:

```
x_vall,x_test,y_vall,y_test = ttt(x_val,y_val,test_size = 0.4)

x_train,x_vall,x_test = np.array(x_train).astype('float32'),np.array(x_vall).astype('float32'),np.array(x_test).astype('float32')
# normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0-1
x_train = x_train / 255.0
x_vall = x_vall / 255.0
x_test = x_test / 255.0
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_vall = np_utils.to_categorical(y_vall)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
num_classes = y_vall.shape[1] #10

#fitting_and_evaluating
model = larger_model()
# Fit the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_vall, y_vall), epochs=50,   batch_size=200)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
```

The output is coming as follows:(from **16th**epoch to **37th** epoch)

```
Epoch 16/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 271s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3013 -    acc: 0.1135 - val_loss: 2.3015 - val_acc: 0.1095
Epoch 17/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 275s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3011 -    acc: 0.1128 - val_loss: 2.3014 - val_acc: 0.1095
Epoch 18/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 270s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3011 -    acc: 0.1124 - val_loss: 2.3015 - val_acc: 0.1095
Epoch 19/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 273s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3012 -    acc: 0.1131 - val_loss: 2.3017 - val_acc: 0.1095
Epoch 20/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 273s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3011 -    acc: 0.1130 - val_loss: 2.3018 - val_acc: 0.1111
Epoch 21/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 272s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3010 -    acc: 0.1127 - val_loss: 2.3013 - val_acc: 0.1095
Epoch 22/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 281s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3006 -    acc: 0.1133 - val_loss: 2.3015 - val_acc: 0.1097
Epoch 23/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 273s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3005 -    acc: 0.1136 - val_loss: 2.3018 - val_acc: 0.1099
Epoch 24/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 276s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3005 -    acc: 0.1135 - val_loss: 2.3022 - val_acc: 0.1116
Epoch 25/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 271s 7ms/step - loss: 2.2998 -    acc: 0.1155 - val_loss: 2.3025 - val_acc: 0.1071
Epoch 26/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 271s 7ms/step - loss: 2.2996 -    acc: 0.1156 - val_loss: 2.3021 - val_acc: 0.1100
Epoch 27/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 272s 7ms/step - loss: 2.2981 -    acc: 0.1168 - val_loss: 2.3024 - val_acc: 0.1078
Epoch 28/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 270s 7ms/step - loss: 2.2970 -    acc: 0.1187 - val_loss: 2.3035 - val_acc: 0.1065
Epoch 29/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 271s 7ms/step - loss: 2.2945 -    acc: 0.1218 - val_loss: 2.3061 - val_acc: 0.1041
Epoch 30/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 270s 7ms/step - loss: 2.2935 -    acc: 0.1223 - val_loss: 2.3059 - val_acc: 0.1003
Epoch 31/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 274s 7ms/step - loss: 2.2906 -    acc: 0.1268 - val_loss: 2.3067 - val_acc: 0.1014
Epoch 32/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 276s 7ms/step - loss: 2.2873 -    acc: 0.1278 - val_loss: 2.3078 - val_acc: 0.1073
Epoch 33/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 292s 7ms/step - loss: 2.2806 -    acc: 0.1368 - val_loss: 2.3118 - val_acc: 0.1034
Epoch 34/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 301s 8ms/step - loss: 2.2744 -    acc: 0.1404 - val_loss: 2.3160 - val_acc: 0.1022
Epoch 35/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 289s 7ms/step - loss: 2.2662 -    acc: 0.1486 - val_loss: 2.3172 - val_acc: 0.1029
Epoch 36/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 295s 8ms/step - loss: 2.2557 -    acc: 0.1543 - val_loss: 2.3162 - val_acc: 0.1087
Epoch 37/50
39200/39200 [==============================] - 308s 8ms/step - loss: 2.2459 -    acc: 0.1632 - val_loss: 2.3275 - val_acc: 0.1083
```

As can be seen, there is very low training as well validation accuracy.

I have tried reducing Dropout(previously it was 0.5 for one of the layers) but still no effect. I doubled the neurons in the last hidden layer,(previously they were 100), still no effect. It seems like, it is something to do with the pre processing of the images as well as the input parameters for the image.
What can be done?

Comment: In fact your model isn't learning anything, which usually points to a bug. I don't see anything overtly wrong. A common error is inputting garbage to the network accidentally. Take the first few images that you're feeding to the network and display them in a debugger before your `fit` step and print out the labels and make sure they match. Do a sanity check on your inputs.

Comment: Yep, I think that is the issue. Could you please check out the dataset yourself as well? I can share the link. [here]https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-identify-the-digits/download/train-file

Comment: I won't have time to run code myself, but if you verify and post any updates you find I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: Your `input_shape=(4, 28, 28)` but by default keras conv2D data format is `channels_last`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @DavidParks , the labels were not matching. Weird. I did some modifications in my code and verified that the labels and images matched. Things are running pretty smoothly now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Richard_wth The line of code: `K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')` , takes care of the input shape. Thanks for replying.

Comment: We've all done that a few times. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied in from comments as the answer:

In fact your model isn't learning anything, which usually points to a bug. I don't see anything overtly wrong. A common error is inputting garbage to the network accidentally. Take the first few images that you're feeding to the network and display them in a debugger before your fit step and print out the labels and make sure they match. Do a sanity check on your inputs.